# How to return a new object each time the old one is modified?

Tags: java

Some code:

```
public class Person {

  private Person(Builder builder) {
    //construct the person object
  }

  public static class Builder {
    public Builder withName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return this;
    }
    public Builder withAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
      return this;
    }
    public Builder withPhone(int phone) {
      this.phone = phone;
      return this;
    }

    //How to add this method?
    public Builder withPerson(Person person) {
      this.person = person;
      return this;
    }

    public Person build() {
      return new Person(this);
    }
  }
}
```

So basically I have an object, a person in this case which has a builder. Now Say I initially build the person with only a `name` and an `age` and get the object `PersonOne`. Now I want the object `PersonOne`to be immutable. So if I want to add a `phone` to `PersonOne` I want to do it such that it returns a `PersonTwo` which has everything that `PersonOne` has and also the new `phone`. So, each time I modify the `Person` object I get a new one and the old one remains immutable. I am not sure how to make this work in java without just blindly copying all the existing attributes of a `Person` object into a new one and then add the new attribute and return a new `Person`. I don't want to do this cause the object I am having has a lot of attributes and a lot of `if` conditions would make the code look bad. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why would you have if conditions ?

Comment: You need just one copy constructor. And the object should be internally mutable, but immutable through public API. Then you can set the field after construction and return the modified copy.

Comment: Well, while constructing the object, if some attributes have not been initialized, you would have to check if they are null or not. Right? So if there are 15 attributes, you would have to check each one of them to see which ones were set in the original object.

Comment: Why would you have to check? It will be as much `null` in the copy as it is in the original.

Comment: @noMAD Just use your builder to copy. Otherwise, you could always use reflection bu that would be a bit nasty, especially if you don't want to copy all the fields

Comment: `withAge()` returns `age` instead of `this` - shouldn't even compile?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a builder, so just use it (more concise that Marko Topolnik's answer) :

```
public class Person {
    public PersonBuilder copy() {
        return new PersonBuilder()
                       .withName(this.name)
                       .withAge(this.age)
                       .withPhone(this.phone);
    }

    public Person changeName(String name) {
        return copy().withName(name).build();
    }

    public Person changeAge(int age) {
        return copy().withAge(age).buid();
    }
}
```

Comment: This introduces the  complication of the Builder, and overhead by creating two new instances on each change. Is there any advantage to it which balances tho cost?

Comment: It does create a new object every time, but this object is available to garbage collection right after the method call. Unless you need to create millions of `Person` in a short time, this does not really matter. Code clarity comes first. I don't think bringing the builder in this class is a complication since it makes the code lighter

Comment: You mean, OP needs both the Builder _and_ an API to transform immutable objects? But even then a copy constructor is simpler than going through the Builder API, and saves the extra allocation. The argument "doesn't really matter" cannot imply "let's throw in extra garbage just for fun"---you have to get something in return, but I don't see that here.

Comment: Using the builder makes the `change` methods much more concise thanks to chaining

Comment: I could also have written `Person p=new Person(this);p.name=name;return p;`. So it comes down to counting characters, semicolons, or other such frivolous measure.

Comment: Chaining on a single line is common, having several statements on the same line is rare and not very nice to read. You can use a Java minifier if you want but that won't make your code any easier to read. In terms of readability I prefer my code, that's all

Comment: Indeed. But it emphasizes what exactly you get in return for another garbage object on the heap.

Comment: This is premature optimization ! This won't matter in most use cases

Comment: If you are so concerned about performance, I guess you can just keep an instance of `PersonBuilder` as the only attribute and use it over and over. It is less natural to me so I would not do it unless I have real performance concerns

Comment: No, it's the other way around: the unmotivated use of Builder is senseless resource management. If my code was severely hacky, unreadable, or had any other smell, you could be excused for bringing in "premature optimization". And BTW once your server app scales up to tens of thousands of requests per second, you'd be surprised how soon the GC overhead becomes an issue.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I completely agree with what you're saying here but the only reason am going this way is cause I know that am not going to be creating more than a few objects for my use case. Also, this maybe slightly out of topic but clojure does this for every data structure it supports. And by this I mean, returning a new DS keeping the old one immutable. It also runs on the JVM so I suppose there is an efficient way to do this.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yup, in that case you can just use the builder as an attribute over and over, even for implementing the getters. This way, no data duplication at all, no extra object, no extra lines of code, and everyone's happy

Comment: @noMAD If your code isn't ending up as the server side of a public multiuser application, indeed there's not much to worry about. However, many times your design choices come back to bite you when you least expect.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik hmm true

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: the builder solution has the strong advantage that it allows `Person` to be implemented as a truly immutable object, read with all-`final` fields. This can outweigh any disadvantage connected to this solution.

Comment: @Holger I've been aware of that, but wanted to see whether it is perceived as any advantage by the Q/A posters. The advantage is not very great, though. It allows safe publication over a data race, but that's about it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: you mean, having a guaranty that accidental modifications are impossible, isn’t worth something? I have a project, where a conceptually immutable data structure needs a tweak for performance reasons and I *really* wish I didn’t need it…

Comment: @Holger It's worth _a bit_, I'd say :) There's less code to inspect. But in a domain-model object like this, there won't be any code to inspect in the first place (it's just getters). In other, more complex classes, I value `final` much more.

Comment: @Holger BTW I had a project recently with a similar requirement on my DTOs, but I used `public final` fields and just bit the bullet and wrote out all the code that returns a transformed object. It wasn't that bad, especially compared to the amount of duplication you need to implement a builder, plus all the getters. I could never stomach that.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following approach (I hope the code can do all the talking):

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private String phone;

  public Person(Person that) {
    this.name = that.name;
    this.age = that.age;
    this.phone = that.phone;
  }

  public Person withName(String name) {
    final Person changed = new Person(this);
    changed.name = name;
    return changed;
  }

  public Person withAge(int age) {
    final Person changed = new Person(this);
    changed.age = age;
    return changed;
  }

  public Person withPhone(String phone) {
    final Person changed = new Person(this);
    changed.phone = phone;
    return changed;
  }

  ...getters...

}
```

Just for fun (not that I'd actually go that far with a simple problem as this), you could implement the above in a slightly more concise manner by making use of lambdas:

```
public Person withPhone(String phone) {
  return copyAndChange((p, newPhone) -> p.phone = newPhone, phone);
}

private <T> Person copyAndChange(BiConsumer<Person, T> action, T newValue) {
  final Person changed = new Person(this);
  action.accept(changed, newValue);
  return changed;
}
```

Comment: You can factor out your methods using a `Function<Person, Person>` as a parameter of the factored out method. If you do so, your code will be shorter and slighlty more efficient than mine. A question comes to my mind though : we create a lot of lambdas since Java 8, are they inlined as static methods in the code or are they contained in separate objects ? In that case, lambdas would imply an overhead comparable to the one in my code, and I never heard someone complaining about it

Comment: Lambdas are never cached per-instance. A non-capturing lambda is cached per-class, which implies only a fixed O(1) space overhead. But in my case it wouldn't be as simple because I'd need, say, a `BiConsumer<Person, Object>` (for example, `(p, phone) -> p.phone = (String)phone`---note the ugly downcast). And with age it would need autoboxing. If I actually needed this in my code, I'd be happy with the solution as in the answer: clean, dumb, and as efficient as it gets given the essential requirement.

Comment: Isn't `person -> person.phone = phone` enough ?

Comment: That would be a `BiConsumer<Person, String>`, which then cannot be used for age. Hm, but type inference could perhaps sort this out for me... then I'd just have autoboxing left. Still, I'd consider such a solution only as an exercise because the problem at hand doesn't warrant all that design.

Comment: There, I added a "just for fun" section with Java 8 :)

Comment: Okay, I had already upvoted your answer and I don't get your update. Anyway, I think you're right, that's going far for nothing

Comment: You mean, you don't see why I use BiConsumer instead of `Function<Person, Person>` you suggested? That's to avoid the capturing lambda: in your example you capture the parameter, forcing instantiation of the lambda in each call. You'd also need to add an ugly `return person` and wrap in braces.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `Builder` with an existing person. First, add the following constructors:

```
public Builder() { /* create an initially empty Builder */ }
public Builder(Person person) {
    /* Initialize the Builder with an existing person */
}
```

Now, to change the phone number:

```
Person personTwo = new Builder(personOne).withPhone(phone).build();
```

By the way, you shouldn't store phone numbers as integers.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference on this is to add an additional constructor in the builder that takes a `Person` and copies the fields that way. This is very similar to Dici's answer but will differ in that you don't add in "change" methods.

```
public Builder(Person person) {
  this.name = person.name;
  this.age = person.age;
  this.phone = person.phone
}
```

The reason I prefer to not add "change" methods is because it just *feels* like it's mutable when you do that.

To change with my solution you would do this:

```
Person coolGuy = ...
coolGuy = new Person.Builder(coolGuy).withAge(-4);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what setters are for.

You basically do not want to use the "classic" ones, then dont use them and keep your fields private. No one is capable to change them then and your object is immutable.

Then you can create custom methods, similar to setters like "changeNumber", which would create new Person, set all parameters with changed phone and returns taht Person (instead of being void).

Comment: You are answering by repeating OP's question. His question is _how_ to implement a `changeNumber` method without an explosion of code duplication.

Comment: "Now I want the object `PersonOne` to be immutable."